# Why do two instances of same class get same instance variable change?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I want to make a GUI that asks the user which two files he wants to open. It presents as an Entry and a Button (two times : one per file), both in the same frame, itself in the root.

Since I want the same thing twice, I defined a class and then instanciated it two times, just with different grid positions. 
It contains a method called by the button that updates the value of the Entry.

It works but when I select a file with whichever button, it writes the file path in **BOTH** Entries. I expect it to write **only in the Entry corresponding to the instance**.

It looks like a class variable issue, but my *attributes are at instance level*, so it should get differentiated with the instances.

Here's my code :

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Entry, filedialog as fd

class Selection:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.load_button = Button(master, text="...", command=self.loadFile)     
        self.filedir = Entry(master, text = " ")    

    def loadFile(self):
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename() 
        self.filedir.delete(0,"end")
        self.filedir.insert(0, self.filename)            

if __name__=='__main__': 

    #-------Defining the Root window
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x600+455+210")

    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

    #-------Defining the Frame  

    f2 = Frame(root, bg='#D5F4E4')

    f2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)             
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)              
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1) 

    #-------Instantiation here (Defining the Widgets) 
    TexteL = Label(f2, text="Please select file L :")          
    TexteT = Label(f2, text="Please select file T :")

    k = Selection(f2)  
    j = Selection(f2) 

    #-------Grid everything
    f2.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky="nsew")

    TexteL.grid(row=0,column=1)
    TexteT.grid(row=2,column=1)

    k.load_button.grid(row=1, column=2) 
    k.filedir.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')

    j.load_button.grid(row=3, column=2) 
    j.filedir.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `text = " "` argument when initializing the `Entry`.  The `text` argument is not used to set the initial text to be displayed in the `Entry`, but rather setting the `textvariable` argument.  As it is set to same `" "`, it will refer to the same internal `variable`. Just remove the `text = " "` will solve the issue.